# Django ListView not using join sql statements on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am quite new to Django and am still learning the basics.  I have been playing around with the generic ListView and I am confused about the sql queries behind the list content generation.  Here's a simple example to illustrate:

My model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField()

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField()
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

My views:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class PhoneList(ListView):
    models=Phone
```

My template:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <tr><td>{{ obj.member }}</td><td>{{ obj.phone }}</td><td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, suppose I have put in some records into the Phone table:

```
1 - member_id=1, phone='123425'  
2 - member_id=2, phone='234234'  
3 - member_id=5, phone='9043234'
...
```

So I run this ListView and everything displays as expected.  The phone numbers are listed alongside members' names.

However, when I use debug_toolbar to look at the underlying sql statements, I see that Django is not using a JOIN statement between the member and phone tables.  Instead, for each phone record, it does a separate query to the member table to get the corresponding member record.

This seems very inefficient.  If I pull up 1000 phone records, it would then do 1000 queries into the database?  Why isn't it using a JOIN query?  I must be missing something.  Btw, I use MySQL as the database.

Comment: You need [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: Could there be sql query caching going on here such that Django doesn't actually hits the db multiple times?

Comment: @Daniel: Ok, thanks.  Let me look into it.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I need to add `queryset = Phone.objects.select_related()` into PhoneList.  Thanks!